# Connection refused on SVN checkout attempt

Tags: linux, svn, terminal

I am using Linux on VMWare Workstation inside windows 7 and i want to access to the URL below in terminal but i always get this error back. I am totally sure that everything is correct because my friend has tried the same on his computer and it worked. Please advise me something about it .It is very important

svn co svn://svn.alunos.di.uminho.pt/projectname --username  ***_*_** --password ***_*_**

svn: E000111: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://svn.alunos.di.uminho.pt/**__**'

svn: E000111: Can't connect to host 'svn.alunos.di.uminho.pt': Connection refused

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the IP address of the VM is being blocked from connecting somehow. It could be being blocked by the server, or an intermediate firewall (because it doesn't recognise the IP address, or because you are using some network like a guest network or wifi, that blocks certain ports or hosts) or it could be that there is no route from the VM to the server.

Basically I would say it's an IT Helpdesk issue; however, if the Helpdesk does not support VMware, or does not support Linux, or does not support connecting to that server, then you will have to ask someone else.